# label is disappear with auto layout if it does not have any string

Tags: ios-autolayout

I am very new in IOS development.
I'm having trouble in auto layout, I have a label and "hello" string in it and I'm deleting characters using button click from string. If i don't use auto layout label is not being disappear(while it does not contain a single character). 
The problem is using auto layout(I have given a standard constrains to top layout),now label is disappearing.

Any one faced the same problem ? have any solution ?
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In auto layout, width of the label is decided on the length of the constraint if width constraint is not added.

Add a width constraint and the label will remain independent of the length of the text.

Comment: Thank you so much Keerthi for replying so soon. It works. :)

Comment: Welcome! :)Please accept the answer if it helped you :)